# Como deixar a chave primária e estrangeira de uma tabela com a constraint NOT NULL no PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou criando chaves primárias e estrangeiras com  a constraint NOT NULL no PostgreSQL, só o jeito que eu estou fazendo isso é indo nas propriedades na tabela e definindo manualmente as chaves como NOT NULL, eu gostaria de fazer isso através dos códigos de criação da tabela.

Logo abaixo está algumas tabelas do meu banco para que possam entender e me ajudar nessa minha dúvida

```
CREATE TABLE endereco_fornecedor (
  cd_endereco_fornecedor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  cidade VARCHAR(30),
  bairro VARCHAR(30),
  endereco VARCHAR(30),
  numero_endereco INT
)

CREATE TABLE telefone_fornecedor (
  cd_telefone_fornecedor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  telefone_fornecedor VARCHAR(15)
)

CREATE TABLE fornecedor (
  cd_fornecedor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  cd_endereco_fornecedor INT,
  cd_telefone_fornecedor INT,
  cnpj_fornecedor VARCHAR(18),
  nome_fornecedor VARCHAR(30),
  email_fornecedor VARCHAR(50),
  foreign key (cd_endereco_fornecedor) references endereco_fornecedor (cd_endereco_fornecedor),
  foreign key (cd_telefone_fornecedor) references telefone_fornecedor (cd_telefone_fornecedor)  
)
```

Comment: Você deseja que os campos cd_endereco_fornecedor e cd_telefone_fornecedor não possam ser nulos?

Comment: Sim, ```NOT NULL``` para todas as chaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para não permitir valores nulos, na criação do campo, basta informar `not null`, exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE fornecedor (
  cd_fornecedor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  cd_endereco_fornecedor INT not null,
  cd_telefone_fornecedor INT not null,
  cnpj_fornecedor VARCHAR(18),
  nome_fornecedor VARCHAR(30),
  email_fornecedor VARCHAR(50),
  foreign key (cd_endereco_fornecedor) references endereco_fornecedor (cd_endereco_fornecedor),
  foreign key (cd_telefone_fornecedor) references telefone_fornecedor (cd_telefone_fornecedor)  
);
```

> Veja online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4b6e9

---

Caso deseje outros campos com tal condição, basta seguir a sintaxe:

```
nome_do_campo tipo_do_campo not null
```

---

> Documentação: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html

Comment: ```NOT NULL``` é uma constraint que funciona no MySQL, e não no PostgreSQL

Comment: @Iury Hittalo A própria documentação do Postgres tem esse exemplo e o link do exemplo online testa em um banco Postgres.

Comment: @Iury: Como não funciona no PostgreSQL???!!!???

Comment: Está gerando algum erro? Se sim, qual?

Comment: Veja que funcionou no meu postgres local também: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc9c0.png

Comment: @DanielMendes desculpe erro meu, isso funciona bem funciona bem.

Comment: @DanielMendes sua resposta é boa, mais toda vez que precisa inserir dados em uma tabela com chaves estrangeiras vai ser sempre necessário inserir os dados da chave estrangeira manualmente.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Se você criar as contraints PK , o campo já se torna NotNull por default.

2 - Você pode criar um Check :

CHECK (column_name IS NOT NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Outra maneira de fazer isso é usando o `SERIAL` nas chaves estrangeiras, assim elas nunca ficam nulas e implementam automaticamente sem precisar inserir os valores da chave.

```
CREATE TABLE endereco_fornecedor (
  cd_endereco_fornecedor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  cidade VARCHAR(30),
  bairro VARCHAR(30),
  endereco VARCHAR(30),
  numero_endereco INT
)

CREATE TABLE telefone_fornecedor (
  cd_telefone_fornecedor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  telefone_fornecedor VARCHAR(15)
)

CREATE TABLE fornecedor (
  cd_fornecedor SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  cd_endereco_fornecedor SERIAL,
  cd_telefone_fornecedor SERIAL,
  cnpj_fornecedor VARCHAR(18),
  nome_fornecedor VARCHAR(30),
  email_fornecedor VARCHAR(50),
  FOREIGN KEY (cd_endereco_fornecedor) REFERENCES endereco_fornecedor (cd_endereco_fornecedor),
  FOREIGN KEY (cd_telefone_fornecedor) REFERENCES telefone_fornecedor (cd_telefone_fornecedor)  
)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Do jeito que fiz não é uma boa prática, pois a chave estrangeira sempre vai ser incrementada e pode ocorrer erros.